# Separation properties of convex set in the n-dimensional Euclidean space

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Let S be a nonempty closed convex set in Rn, not containing the origin. I would like to find a hyperplane that strictly separates S and the origin. Does it exists?

Comment: It is true in topological vector spaces since you can find a convex open set containing the origin that does not intersect $S$. Then the Hahn Banach theorem gives the existence of a separating functional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**

Name $x$ the orthogonal projection of $x$ onto $S$. By hypothesis $x$ exists as $S$ is a non empty closed convex of the finite dimensional space $\mathbb R^n$. Also $x \neq 0$.

The mid hyperplane $H$ of $[0, x]$ segment is one hyperplane answering your question.